# send gcm messages FROM mobile devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was playing around with the GoogleCloudMessaging System, and was wondering if it is possible to create GCM Messages from Mobile Apps itself. So just for brainstorming purpose what are the problems that I might face? Why would this be a bad idea?

Comment: "Why would this be a bad idea?" Android applications are basically (and mostly) client applications. Giving client the power to behave like a server is... yeah kind of a bad idea, unless you want to spam everybody. But yes I guess it can work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so just invoke your server method  for user generated **gcm request** and now server will request to gcm cloud to generate gcm Message.